# Use of curly braces (accolades) "{}"

Tags: ponctuation

What are the formal or informal rules of using curly braces (*accolades*) "{}" in French?  (I do not know English rules either, but currently I am interested in French.)

Comment: I'm not sure what we are discussing here. I, for one, don't remember any meaning or purpose that readers might universally attribute to curly braces in either language, so unfortunately I can't help you in knowing the rules. Would you be interested in any particular (possibly technical or non-standard) use of the braces? If so, please describe it in the question, and provide a few examples.

Comment: Interestingly, Wikipedia uses some accolades in its introduction to the French *Ponctuation* article: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponctuation . Most likely as an alternative to brackets ( and )

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, i was rather interested in any standard meaning of curly braces, if such exists.  For example: ["Trait de plume qui, dans un compte, etc. joint plusieurs articles. C.-M. Gattel, Nouveau dict. portatif de la langue française, 1797."](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accolades).

Comment: I would also like to understand what could constitute informally acceptable usage of *accolades* in French.

Answer (score 5):

Selon [Les règles de la composition typographique](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_R%C3%A8gles_de_la_composition_typographique), trouvées sur Wikisource:

> Les accolades servent à embrasser plusieurs lignes ou plusieurs
>   colonnes, et leur pointe se tourne vers la ligne ou les lignes
>   auxquelles les lignes ou colonnes embrassées se rapportent :
>
> [image]
>
> Le centre saillant de l’accolade placée verticalement doit toujours
>   être tourné du côté qui contient le moins d’étendue en hauteur :
>
> [image]
>
> Si l’étendue des deux parties est la même, le centre saillant se
>   tourne du côté qui contient le moins d’articles :
>
> [image]

Comment: I think he was refferring to their use in {a sentence} like that.

Comment: @Nathan: I think so as well. But that book only mention that usage. One can infer that _accolades_ are not used in sentences (which indeed is my own experience).

Comment: Aussi, comparer [ceci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3342) et [cela](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accolade). Merci.